# How to map URL data in a Single object using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have a single page application using vue js. Now I have to get data from 3 different source URL and then need to map in an object to use it on the application.

Or is it better to get it from ONE URL after mapping it on the backend?

```js
$.get(furl, function(data) {
  this.items1 = data;
});

$.get(furl, function(data) {
  this.items2 = data;
});

$.get(furl, function(data) {
  this.items3 = data;
});
// if I want to merge it here. I am not getting items1, items2, items3 here.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Promises:

```
Promise.all([
  new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $.get( furl, function( data ) {
      resolve(data);
    });
  }),

  new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $.get( furl, function( data ) {
      resolve(data);
    });
  }),

  new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $.get( furl, function( data ) {
      resolve(data);
   });
  })
]).then(function(results) {
  // The items will be available here as results[0], results[1], results[2], etc.
});
```

Written more efficiently and elegantly:

```
function promisifiedGet(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $.get(url, resolve);
  });
}

Promise.all([
  promisifiedGet(furl1),
  promisifiedGet(furl2),
  promisifiedGet(furl3)
]).then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: `Promise.all([$.get(url), $.get(url2), $.get(url3)]).then(...)`.

Comment: @Bert So `$.get()` returns a thenable?

Comment: I don't know of an ajax library that doesn't return a promise these days.

Comment: @Bert OK then, cool! It wasn't always that way with `jQuery.ajax()` and my knowledge of jQuery is very obsolete.

Comment: Thanks, It's working :)

Now, Could you tell me How I can throw this result data in another function?

Comment: @Sharat Call that other function with the result as argument(s)

Comment: @MikaelLennholm yes i tried like this way but getting following error.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'allusersData' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using jQuery for the ajax calls?  In this case, I would recommend using the [when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to which will monitor the deffered objects that come back from the ajax queries and wait for them all to complete.

```
var a1 = $.get( furl, function( data ) {
            this.items1 = data;
   });


var a2 = $.get( furl, function( data ) {
            this.items2 = data;
   });


 var a3 = $.get( furl, function( data ) {
            this.items3 = data;
   });


$.when(a1, a2, a3, function(data1, data2, data3) {
   // here is where you merge them into your object and continue the rest of your code
   var o = {};
   o.items1 = data1;
   o.items2 = data2;
   o.items3 - data3;
});
```

Comment: This is unlikely to work in Vue due to scoping `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `this` inside a function, which in tern might be Either the global object or undefined if there is a `use strict` directive. Have you tried creating a variable out of the callback functions and in each callback, add the `data` to that array?

Like so:

```
let results = {};
$.get( furl, function( data ) {
        results.items1 = data;
 });


$.get( furl, function( data ) {
        results.items2 = data;
 });


 $.get( furl, function( data ) {
        results.items3 = data;
 });
```